# My stronghold spawned with one room

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

My eyes of ender took me to a stronghold with only one room that makes it up, I downloaded X-rays to see if I can see more rooms unattached but it was just one room with no portal(I play on MCPE)I’m trying to keep my world cheat free too, help

Comment: And what's your problem?

Comment: “Cheat free” “downloaded xray” might be too late.

Comment: Then, if this is screwed up, you need to find another one

Answer (score 2):

There are 127 other strongholds. As much as this stinks, your best option is to just find another one.

Comment: No. This is Bedrock Edition, so there are infinite strongholds per world (I’ve seen strongholds millions of blocks out)